# Is there a way to see that sqoop has finished writing to a file?

Tags: hadoop, etl, sqoop

Let's say a sqoop job is writing incremental imports to an hdfs directory. 
Another (non-sqoop) job is periodically moving data from this directory somewhere else for processing.
I'd like this job to not move files that are being modified by sqoop at the moment. Is there a way to have ready files renamed to a certain pattern once they are good to be moved?

If files are not moved, does sqoop just append new content to existing part-m-000x files each time?

Answer (score 0):

Look at how Ambari/HDFS upload process works. When you upload a file to hdfs, during the upload of file "xxxx.txt" Ambari uploads it as "xxxx.txt._COPYING". When the upload is completed it simply renames the file to the right name.

If your other sqoop process searches for ".txt" files it won't see it before it is renamed and therefore completed and ready to be moved.

Done this in the past and works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I'm asking if there's a way to make sqoop work the same way (or if it works this way by default)?

Comment: Doesn't work this way by default. You would have to script it. You could simply wrap the sqoop utility in a script that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop uses MapReduce under the hood and M/R jobs by default store the results in a `_temporary` sub-directory while in progress:

[Task Side-Effect Files](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Task_Side-Effect_Files)

> (...) when the OutputCommitter is FileOutputCommitter, maintains a special `${mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir}/_temporary/_${taskid}` sub-directory accessible via `${mapreduce.task.output.dir}` for each task-attempt on the FileSystem where the output of the task-attempt is stored. On successful completion of the task-attempt, the files in the `${mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir}/_temporary/_${taskid}` (only) are promoted to `${mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir}`. Of course, the framework discards the sub-directory of unsuccessful task-attempts. This process is completely transparent to the application.

I have just executed a Sqoop import to verify this information and Sqoop does indeed work this way.